# Doesn't getting Selling Plan data on the product page

Tags: api, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I've implemented a Selling Plan in Shopify through a public app (mutation sellingPlanGroupCreate...), the selling plan is attached to the product correctly
[image]

But when I try to purchase the product at the checkout, it is showing **0**, It should be showing the price according to the selling plan.

[image]

Here is my query for creating a selling plan is Shopify

```
mutation {
            sellingPlanGroupCreate(
                input: {
                    name: "Pre-order"
                    merchantCode: "pre-order"
                    options: [
                        "Pre-order"
                    ]
                    sellingPlansToCreate: [
                    {
                        name: "Pre Order Product with 100% deposit 2023-07-24"
                        category: PRE_ORDER
                        options: [
                            "100% deposit. No Due Balance 2023-07-24"
                        ]
                        billingPolicy: {
                            fixed: {
                                checkoutCharge: {type: PERCENTAGE, value: {percentage: 40}}
                                remainingBalanceChargeTrigger: EXACT_TIME
                                remainingBalanceChargeExactTime: "2022-07-24"
                            }
                        }
                        pricingPolicies: [
                            {
                                fixed: {
                                    adjustmentType: PERCENTAGE
                                    adjustmentValue: { percentage: 15.0 }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                        deliveryPolicy: {fixed: {fulfillmentTrigger: UNKNOWN}}
                        inventoryPolicy: {reserve: ON_FULFILLMENT}
                    }
                    ]
                }
                resources: {productVariantIds: ["gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42791380287619","gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42791380320387"], productIds: []}
            ) {
                sellingPlanGroup {
                    id
                }
                userErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
            }
        }
```

**Any idea why I'm getting this?**

**Please Help...**

Thanks

Comment: Is this a question about programming (where is the code?) or on how to use Shopify (which would be off-topic here)? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can also read [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to make sure it's on-topic.

Comment: I have added the code that I am using for creating a selling plan in Shopify

Comment: If that is the "code" you have, why the PHP tag? I don't know what format that is, but it's not PHP.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Ok, I have removed the PHP tag, It's a Shopify GraphQL API Query.